# Linker cant find FLTK functions definitions

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, libcurl, fltk

Im new to C++ and making project using FLTK and cURL. Currently Im trying to compile my app for Windows using MinGW g++.
Ive put files from FLTK and cURL include and lib folders into my own include and lib folders inside my project folder.
[image]
[image]

Then Im trying to compile it using
`g++ main.cpp -o out.exe -Wall -Iinclude -Llib`

But getting list of errors

```
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x218): undefined reference to `Fl_Widget::deactivate()'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x42e): undefined reference to `Fl::check()'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x440): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x469): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x486): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4a5): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4b2): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4c2): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x6a5): undefined reference to `Fl::check()'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x887): undefined reference to `Fl::check()'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa50): undefined reference to `Fl_Widget::copy_label(char const*)'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa75): undefined reference to `Fl_Widget::activate()'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xc98): undefined reference to `Fl_Widget::label(char const*)'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xca5): undefined reference to `Fl_Widget::activate()'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xcf6): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::Fl_Window(int, int, char const*)'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xd38): undefined reference to `Fl_Box::Fl_Box(int, int, int, int, char const*)'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xd7a): undefined reference to `Fl_Box::Fl_Box(int, int, int, int, char const*)'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xdbf): undefined reference to `Fl_Progress::Fl_Progress(int, int, int, int, char const*)'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe04): undefined reference to `Fl_Input::Fl_Input(int, int, int, int, char const*)'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe49): undefined reference to `Fl_Return_Button::Fl_Return_Button(int, int, int, int, char const*)'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xef6): undefined reference to `Fl_Input_::static_value(char const*)'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf2b): undefined reference to `Fl_Group::end()'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1025): undefined reference to `Fl_Window::show(int, char**)'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x102d): undefined reference to `Fl::run()'
C:\Users\TYMURP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxAfSN5.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN11Fl_Progress5valueEf[__ZN11Fl_Progress5valueEf]+0x18): undefined reference to `Fl_Widget::redraw()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `-Llib` adds the folder `lib` as a folder for the linker to look for libraries but does not actually link to any specific library. The linker will not link to any of the files in that folder unless you tell it to do so using `-l`

Comment: @drescherjm
Yeah, Ive tried this way too. It successfully builds this way on my Linux machine, but I cant do it on Windows
Here is full error log when I`m using `-lcurl` and `-lfltk` [Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/2vye5vaJ)

Answer (score 2):

Add linker flags `-lfltk` and `-lcurl` to actually link with the libraries. So your command should look like:

```bash
g++ main.cpp -o out.exe -Wall -Iinclude -Llib -lfltk -lcurl
```

If you are doing a static build you may need to add more libraries that these libraries depend upon.

Comment: I wasnt sure which lib files were exactly necessary as dependency so Ive included them all
`g++ main.cpp -o out.exe -Wall -Iinclude -Llib -lfltk -lcurl -lfltk_forms -lfltk_gl -lfltk_images -lfltk_jpeg -lfltk_png -lfltk_z -lgsasl -lnghttp2 -lnghttp3 -lngtcp2 -lngtcp2_crypto_openssl -lssh2 -lssl -lz -lzstd -lbrotlicommon -lbrotlidec`

Here is full error log
[Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/2vye5vaJ)

I get same result if I include -lcurl and -lfltk only

Comment: Normally `pkg-config` can help you list all static dependencies, but then you would also need the `.pc` files that come with the libraries. But you don't seem to have them.

Comment: Problem not in listing all of them but that they dont work.
Is CLI command itself correct? Maybe something wrong with my system setup?

Comment: On Windows the order of the libraries is also important.

Answer (score 0):

Where is main.cpp relative to lib.  The compile line

```
g++ main.cpp -o out.exe -Wall -Iinclude -Llib -lfltk -lcurl
```

Assumes the following structure

```
+--main.cpp
+--include
+--lib
   +--libfltk.a
   +--libcurl.a
```

Have you had a look at lib - are there nested x86 and x64 directories?
If you have lib somewhere else, say in /usr/lib/fltk or in /home/xxx/fltk, then the -L parameter needs to change.  Something like

```
g++ main.cpp -o out.exe -Wall -Iinclude -L/home/xxx/fltk/lib -lfltk -lcurl
```

Comment: I`m using Windows 10, not Linux. And not, those folders are nested directly inside project folder.